# Input Field Styling - CSS problem

Tags: css

i am trying to create an input box like below

[image]

These are the rules i have attached

```
input {
    height:30px;
    width:286px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-background-clip: padding;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border-color:#cccccc;
    padding:0 10px;
}
```

But i am getting an inner box shawdow like this.

[image]

Any idea how to remove that inner shawdow ?

Online Editor: http://jsfiddle.net/c3JCx/

Comment: nope. i still get the inner shadow

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try replacing:

```
border-color:#cccccc;
```

with:

```
border: 1px solid #cccccc;
```

this will make the border with solid color as shown on the first image ... the default `border-style` is `inset` and it looks kind of "3D" as described in w3schools (second image)

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
border-color:#cccccc;
```

with

```
border: 1px solid #cccccc;
```