# html input and select different height

Tags: html, select, input

I set height:

```
input,select{height: 20px;}
```

but in browser it height is `input : 20px` and `select 18px`, I dont know why because before input and select was reseted. If I remove `<!DOCTYPE html>` then is ok, but then IE not centering page.

Comment: Review: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10001291/aligning-text-and-select-boxes-to-the-same-width-in-css

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767612/issue-with-input-select-tag-height-in-form

Comment: @Vucko thanks, maybe you know default border color ? ?

Comment: @Tomas Lietuva, of what ? Select or input box ?
For select: http://jsfiddle.net/CUA9p/632/

For input: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327703/input-field-styling-css-problem

I personally love to work with transparent input field on some image.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This can be corrected by setting the `box-sizing` property of your elements to `border-box`:

```
input, select{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Vendor specific prefixes like `moz-` or `webkit-` might apply.

Comment: Man, I've been looking for this for 10 minutes. Worst 10 minutes of my day!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to set the height of my `SELECT` to exactly what I wanted in IE8 and 9.  The trick is to set the `box-sizing` property to `content-box`. Doing so will set the content area of the `SELECT` to the height, but keep in mind that `margin`, `border` and `padding` values will not be calculated in the width/height of the `SELECT`, so adjust those values accordingly.

```
select {
    display: block;
    padding: 6px 4px;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:content-box;
    box-sizing:content-box;
    height: 15px;
}
```

Here is a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8fkgg/2/). Would you mind confirming and marking the appropriate answer?